# How to emit a blank line using yaml-cpp

Tags: yaml-cpp

Using yaml-cpp, version 0.2.5 ...

I would like to emit a blank line between entries in a list (for readability purposes).
Is this possible?

I have tried experimentation with the Verbatim, and Null manipulators, but have not had success.

Comment: If the owner of yaml-cpp reads this, it looks like it may be a simple addition.  Would they (you) consider a patch to do this? http://groups.google.com/group/ocio-dev/msg/b5ddc3019992998f

Comment: Sure! I opened this as http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=77; I'm not 100% sure that the above patch will work in all cases, but I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

As of [revision 420](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/source/detail?r=420), this is possible:

```
YAML::Emitter emitter;
emitter << YAML::BeginSeq;
emitter << "a" << YAML::Newline << "b" << "c";
emitter << YAML::EndSeq;
```

produces

```
---
- a

- b
- c
```

I decided to go with `YAML::Newline` instead of `YAML::Newline(n)` since I found

1. I usually just wanted a single newline.
2. I kept accidentally typing `YAML::Newline`, which implicitly cast the function to a `bool` (specifically, `true`), so I figured other people would probably make the same mistake.

If you just want to patch your copy (and not sync with the trunk), use revisions 418-420. (Note: it's *slightly* trickier than the patch in the link you posted, since you have to be careful about a newline after an implicit key. See the comment on the (now closed) [Issue 77](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=77) for more details.)

Comment: @Jeremy, if you like, you can select this answer as the "correct" answer by clicking the checkmark to the left.